# I Want to Find Daily Calculation interest in Excel Sheet Based on Some Requirement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-solver

[image]

I need to find Daily Calculating interest
Interest As 1 %

1. 1 jan Closing Bal as -100. No Need to Calculate interest For Jan 1
   For Next 2 days have No transaction. So No Need to Calculate Interest For Jan 2 & 3
   Because 1 jan Closing Bal is -100
2. 5 Jan closing Bal  as 100. So Calculate Interest For 5 Jan.
   Then 8 jan Closing Bal 0. So No need to Calculate For 8 Jan.
   But need to to Calculate For 6 & 7 Jan Taken the 5th Closing Bal And calculate For 2 days Interest  And Put into 8 Jan
3. 9 Jan Closing Bal as 100. so calculate Interest For 9 Jan.
   Then 12 Jan as -100 so No Need to Calculate for 12 Jan
   But Need to Calculate 10 & 11 Jan Taken 9 Jan Closing Bal And Calculate for 2 Days Interest And Put into 12 Jan

4)14 Jan Closing Bal as 0. so no need to Calculate For 14 Jan
Then 16 jan as 400 So  Need to Calculate for 16 Jan
But no Need  to Calculate 15 Jan because Jan 14 Closing bal As 0.

I Need to Find  in Excel For Calculating Interest Based on  requirement Can u help me

Comment: No One Can solve this problem. adding addition column also to Find the Solution

Comment: Please share the formula to calculate the interest and put the sample data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) format and share the expected result on each case.